# iPhone gloss effect xcode 4.1

Tags: iphone, ios

I am using Xcode 4.1 and disabled the gloss effect for icons.
works fine on my simulator and real device.

but now after uploading and release in the app store there the gloss effect is on my icon! is that a bug or what can i do?

thx
chris

Comment: I am having the exact same issue -- guess I'll contact apple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure that in the .plist file, the option:

```
  Icon already includes gloss effects = YES
```

If the problem is only on the 512*512 (Large) icon, the effect should be removed after uploading the binary that. If even then the problem persists, you should log in to itunesconnect.com and click on the "Contact Us" icon, the Apple Team will be more than happy to help You
:)

Answer (score 3):

Just check your code which you have provide for release.
the reflection is added by the device UNLESS you set the UIPrerenderedIcon in info.plist to true. Check info.plist for
<key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
<true/>

Comment: also in the dev itunesconnect app detail it shows:
Prerendered Icon Flag :  true

Comment: then you have to connect apple support team. they can help you for your problem.

Answer (score 2):

finally it was a problem in the store. i wrote apple and they solved it :)

Answer (score 0):

Does your AppStore icon has the exact size and ppi? It should be 512x512 and 72ppi. I have read somewhere before that they had this problem solved by reuploading the icon with correct size and ppi.

Comment: also in the dev itunesconnect app detail it shows:
Prerendered Icon Flag :  true